# Pandas storing 1000's of dataframe objects

Tags: python, object, pandas, dataframe, storage

I am working on a large project that does SPC analysis and have 1000's of different unrelated dataframe objects. Does anyone know of a module for storing objects in memory?  I could use a python dictionary but would like it more elaborate and functional mechanisms like locking, thread safe, who has it and a waiting list etc? I was thinking of creating something that behaves like my local public library system.  The way it checks in and out books to one owner ...etc.

Comment: I should have mentioned I need this to be in memory only for speed

Answer (score 2):

[HDF5-pytables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables) is a pretty good storage back-end for pandas.

[Pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) can expand to be managed like a file system BUT care must be taken if you need any kind of multi-access *(if you really need that you should use a traditional database that provides these features)*.

Answer (score 1):

Redis with redis-py is one solution. Redis is really fast and there are nice Python bindings. Pytables, as mentioned above, is a good choice as well. PyTables is HDF5, and is really really fast.